# Removing Partitions for Fresh Windows 7 Install

Tags: formatting

Okay, after a lot .. A LOT .. of trying Linux versions, I would like to return to Windows 7 please...

I have my Windows 7 Home Premium Key.  Downloading a SP1 ISO right now for the fresh install.

Now I know windows is a bit primitive so I would like to know what steps I have to take (I am on Fedora right now) to make sure that there wont be a ton of partitions and allocated space when I install Windows.

Basically, I would like to remove EVERYTHING. And just start from Scratch with a 750GB harddisk that is not split up, and gives full attention to the only OS that is gonna be installed..

Right now I have a few unusable partitions, and I had trouble installing windows 7 once before, so please help me out before I take a massive magnet to erase the Disk :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While going through the installation, you will reach the below screen:
[image]

Just delete the partitions you want and leave one which will include the whole HD space.